# Inline svg as directive (Firefox issue)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, svg, inline-svg

In my project, I am using Inline svgs as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div style="display: none">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <symbol id="dropdown" viewBox="0 0 3.359 1.929"><path d="M1.68 1.929a.29.29 0 0 1-.204-.083L.085.484a.28.28 0 0 1 0-.401.293.293 0 0 1 .409 0L1.68 1.244 2.865.083a.294.294 0 0 1 .41 0 .28.28 0 0 1 0 .401l-1.39 1.361a.3.3 0 0 1-.205.084z"></path></symbol>
  </svg>
</div>
<div one-svg svg-href="'dropdown'"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('oneSvg', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'inline-svg.html',
        scope: {
            svgHref: "=",
            svgClass: "="
        }
    };
});
```

**inline-svg.html**

```
<svg ng-class="svgClass">
    <use ng-href="{{ '#' + svgHref }}" ng-attr-href="{{ '#' + svgHref }}" href=""></use>
</svg>
```

Here is the [**fiddle**](http://plnkr.co/edit/gA3VF8WYg0IX0U2LCUjq?p=preview)

The above created directive is working only in Chrome and IE10 but not in **Firefox (v 50.1.0)**.

If I add the inline SVG without directive, it is working fine in Firefox. Please help me to make the directive work even in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the changes in this [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/l5FcvAGAHu203jlsBWXd?p=preview).
It worked for me on FireFox, Chrome and Safari.

Html:

```
<svg style="display:none;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" <svg style="display:none;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="dropdown" viewBox="0 0 3.359 1.929">
      <path d="M1.68 1.929a.29.29 0 0 1-.204-.083L.085.484a.28.28 0 0 1 0-.401.293.293 0 0 1 .409 0L1.68 1.244 2.865.083a.294.294 0 0 1 .41 0 .28.28 0 0 1 0 .401l-1.39 1.361a.3.3 0 0 1-.205.084z"></path>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div one-svg="dropdown"></div>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('oneSvg', function() {
    return {
        template: '<svg ng-class="svgClass"><use xlink:href="{{ \'#\' + href }}"></use></svg>',
        scope: {
            href: "@oneSvg",
            svgClass: "=?"
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem was I was using `ng-attr-href` and `ng-href` attributes in that template.